# I can not ping webpage but can open it using browser

Tags: networking, ping

I have problem with webpage: http://webase.sk/.
When I try to ping it there is no response

```
~$ ping webase.sk
PING webase.sk (213.215.116.120) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- webase.sk ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10080ms
```

When I tried to add ip 213.215.116.120 to my browser I can see just blank page. I tried also nmap but with no success. There is some special protection in this web page or why I can not get rigth ip of it ?

Comment: Well, not every server responds to ping.

Comment: It appears you did not let `ping` complete the request. Try `ping -c 1 webase.sk` - it'll `ping` once and exit. Do not use `^C`

Comment: @BharadwajRaju it sends 11 packets as you can see in the report.

Comment: If you just want the webpage ip address, try `nslookup webase.sk`

Comment: hm but why when I add address 213.215.116.120 I can see just blank page ?

Comment: Loading the page in your browser is a totally other story then pinging the servers ip address. So while the server might not answer an icmp ping it might for sure react on calls for its webserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could simply be a firewall blocking pings and a web site that only responds to a specific URL not the ip address.

Comment: so there is no legal way how to get ip ?